# How to block traffic from incoming port?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, ddos

I'm facing an issue with DDoS attack at my server, the ips which attack are different but their port is the same example:

120.20.30:3003
193.25.54:3003
201.54.11:3003

Is there any iptables rule which I can apply to block all traffic from these ips?

Comment: iptables -I INPUT -sport 3003 -j DROP  (untested) will block these probes. Is that what you want, or do you need a much more complex solution which drops any traffic after traffic from a system on port 3003 is seen?

Comment: iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 3003 -j DROP